# Fail working with my github reps without password entering

Tags: github, ssh

Hello,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                I try to make working with my github reps without password entering and for this I copied content of my 
/home/serge/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, which has rows like

```
ssh-rsa AAA ... zJL serge@serge
```

file into “SSH and GPG keys” page
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TowsC.jpg

In /home/serge/.ssh/config I see rows:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_rsa
    Hostname bitbucket.org
    User git 

Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_rsa
    Hostname github.com
    User git
```

I entered password on saving and restarted ssh service with command : 
service ssh restart

But entering command:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I forced to enter my username/password.

What did I miss ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 2**
1)Do you mean My Repository->Settings->Deploy keys clicking on “Add deploy key” button?
I tried and got “Key is already in use” error message...

2) After I tried to delete existing SSH key in “https://github.com/settings/keys” of my account, so at this time I have no
SSH keys associated with my account account.

3) I repeated point 1 successfully, but anyway commiting new changes on my laptop and pushing them with command

```
git push -u origin master
```

I forced to enter my username/password.

Looks like My Repository->Settings->Deploy keys was wrong place ?

Thanks!

Comment: have you added the public key to your repository?

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2